# gambler's ruin problem - probability of ruin

Tags: probability, markov-chains, recursion

I am analyzing the problem:

> If we play a game where I start with \$2 and you start with \$1, and I have a probability of 1/3 of winning \$1 from you and you have a 1/3 probability of winning \$1 from me, what is the probability that I win all of your money?

The proposed solution is built on the two equations below

```
1. Probability of opponent winning from $2 =
          P(opponent wins | opponent wins dollar) + 
          P(opponent wins | opponent ties for dollar) + 
          P(opponent wins | opponent loses dollar) 

2. Probability of opponent winning from $1 =
        P(opponent wins | opponent wins dollar) + 
        P(opponent wins | opponent ties for dollar) + 
        P(opponent wins | opponent loses dollar)
```

$$1. \quad P_2 = (1/3) + (1/3)P_2 + (1/3)P_1$$
$$2. \quad P_1 = (1/3)P_2 + (1/3)P_1 + (1/3) (0)$$

so that $P_1=1/3, \ \ P_2 =  2/3$

My understanding is that infinitely many scenarios might occur (is that correct?). 
**However I don't understand the construction of the equations (1. and 2.)**. 
Could anybody explain in simple terms the logic used? Do the equations reflect the infinite scenarios?

Comment: What happens when neither person wins?  (you have the probability of each winning at 1/3- that doesn't sum to 1.)

Comment: The number of rounds can be arbitary large (in theory), this implies that infinite many scenarios are possible. Since there is no limit of the number of rounds, we cannot just add finite many probabilities. We need a recursion to get the result.

Comment: @ Peter could you please demonstrate/explain in simple terms the solution using the recursion?

Comment: Look at the player with $1$ dollar. If he loses the first round, he also loses the match (Therefore the $0$). If he ties, then the probability to win the match has not changed. If he wins, he is in the position, player $2$ had at the beginning ($2$ dollars versus $1$ dollar). Since the events cannot occur simulaneously, the probability that the player wins, is the sum of these probabilities. Similar for the other player.

Comment: An easier way to get the result : If we ignore ties, the probability, that the player with $1$ dollar wins the match is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ times the probability that the player with $2$ dollars wins. If the probability that the player with $2$ dollars wins, is $p$, we get $p+\frac{1}{2}p=1$, which gives $p=\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: @ Peter I don't get it. how does the equation $p+\frac{1}{2}p=1$ reflect the infinitly many cases?

Comment: It doesn't. It is a (much simpler) recursion using that the probability that one of the players eventually wins, is $1$. This is not trivial, and I do not know how this can be proven. The recursion you mentioned also supposes that one of the players must eventually win the match.

Comment: @Peter First, let's get ties out of the way. If we keep forcing rounds until we get a non-tie, then both players are equally likely to win a round at a probability of 1/2. This can be shown using an infinite series: 1/3 if the player wins the first time, plus 1/3*1/3 if there is a tie and then the player wins, and so on.

Comment: Now, we are playing so that in each round, a player must win and each player has a 1/2 chance of winning a round. To go on infinitely, the person with only one dollar has to receive a dollar so they don't lose, so the only way this can happen is if a dollar goes from I to you, then you to I, then I to you, and so on. The probability of this outcome is $(1/2)^\infty=0$, so it is essentially impossible for the game never to end and thus the game must end in a finite number of rounds.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, the equations reflect the infinite scenarios because they use recursion: $P_2$ and $P_1$ are in both sides of the equation, which represents the repetitive nature of these infinite scenarios.

I am pretty sure your original equations are wrong. It should be like this:

```
1. Probability of opponent winning from $2 =
        P(opponent wins dollar)*P(opponent wins | opponent wins dollar) + 
        P(opponent ties for dollar)*P(opponent wins | opponent ties for dollar) + 
        P(opponent loses dollar)*P(opponent wins | opponent loses dollar) 

2. Probability of opponent winning from $1 =
        P(opponent wins dollar)*P(opponent wins | opponent wins dollar) + 
        P(opponent ties for dollar)*P(opponent wins | opponent ties for dollar) + 
        P(opponent loses dollar)*P(opponent wins | opponent loses dollar)
```

I am assuming you see how I did this, although if you don't, you can ask me in the comments. This is important because the probabilities I just added are all $1/3$, which is where all of the $1/3$s in the second set of equations come from.

Now, let's look at equation 1.

- `P(opponent wins | opponent wins dollar)` is $1$ because if the opponent wins another dollar, then they have all three dollars, so they win the game.
- `P(opponent wins | opponent ties for dollar)` is the scenario where the opponent is in the same place they just were because nothing changed. Thus, the probability they win is the same, which is $P_2$.
- `P(opponent wins | opponent loses dollar)` is the scenario where the opponent has only one dollar left, so their probability of winning is $P_1$.

Thus, from our original equation and the above reasoning, we get:
$$P_2=1/3\cdot 1+1/3\cdot P_2+1/3\cdot P_1$$

Equation 2 is similar, but somewhat different:

- `P(opponent wins | opponent wins dollar)` is the scenario where the opponent now has two dollars, so the probability of winning is $P_1$.
- `P(opponent wins | opponent ties for dollar)` puts the opponent in the same place they just were because nothing changed. Thus, the probability they win is the same, which is $P_1$.
- `P(opponent wins | opponent loses dollar)` is the scenario where the opponent loses because they have zero dollars left. Thus, the probability of them winning is $0$.

From our original equation and the above reasoning, we get:

$$P_1=1/3\cdot P_1+1/3\cdot P_2+1/3\cdot 0$$

Hopefully, this answer helps you understand how infinite scenarios can be describes using linear equations like this because the infinite scenarios are just leaping between the opponent having one dollar and the opponent having two dollars, which is just $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Comment: the way the conditional probabilities are built confuses me. does the "opponent" in each conditional expression refers to the same player?  maybe referencing it player1 (starting with 2)  and player2 (starting with 1) would be clearer.

Comment: @Michal There is no need to talk about the other player. That would just make things more confusing. The "opponent" is always the same player and just represents a generic player; it's just that they progress through different points in the game. At the beginning, "I" is at 2 dollars, so their probability of winning at the beginning is $P_2$, which "you" is at 1 dollars, so their probability of winning at the beginning is $P_1$. I agree that the wording is confusing and it should just be "player," but I went off of the sketch you gave me.